# Examples of Intuitionistic Proof

Tags: alternative-proof, intuitionistic-logic

For uni I need to write a paper and give a presentation on intuitionism, and I am looking for nice examples of theorems or other results to prove or disprove intuitionistically. One example I found was that, intuitionistically, you can disprove the intermediate value theorem. As a counterpart to this I also want to prove another theorem or result via construction which you would otherwise or would typically prove by contradiction of its negation. Does anyone have nice examples of this I could use?

Any suggestions at all would be appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe useful: [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/)

Comment: See e.g. Errett Bishop, [Foundations of constructive analysis (McGraw-Hill, 1967)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Foundations_of_Constructive_Analysis/Z7I-AAAAIAAJ)